# Alert Automatic Disappear function

Tags: reactjs

My aim is to give the user to see the alert at starting of the my page without clicking any button.And after a while it should be disappear automatically i am trying this on reactjs so any body help me out to find which logic should i apply

Answer (score 1):

First render your alert component. Define a boolean state variable with initial value false.

then update that state variable with setTimeout.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export const Alert = () => {
  const [timeIsUp, setTimeIsUp] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTimeIsUp(true);
    }, 5000);
  }, []);

  if (timeIsUp) {
    return null;
  }

  return <div>your actual alert component content</div>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this link: [custom-modal-popup-component](https://dev.to/satishnaikawadi2001/build-custom-modal-popup-component-in-react-js-29g5)

Also just make the state of modal true at fist and add a setTimeout in useEffect and make it to false after a desired time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `class components` or `functional components` for rendering your React page?

What you're looking for is called `life cycles`, i highly recomend you taking a look in [ReactJS life cycle docs.](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html)

The life cycle method that executes or do something when the page is loaded has two usages:

If you're using `class components`, there is a native method you can call inside your component called `ComponentDidMount()`, his usage is available in [docs here.](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)

Now, if you're using `functional components`, you need to take a look on `useEffect` in [React Hooks.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

After that, you can take a look in `setTimeout` native method from `javascript` as observed.

Hope this helps too!